# How to delete rows after the item which equals to exact value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following dataframe

```
Block_id step name 
1         1    Marie 
1         2    Bob
1         3    John
1         4    Lola
2         1    Alex
2         2    John
2         3    Kate
2         4    Herald
3         1    Alec
3         2    Paul
3         3    Rex
```

As you can see data frame is sorted by block_id and then by step. I want to delete only in one block_id everything after the row where I have name John(the row with John as well). So the desired output would be

```
Block_id step name 
1         1    Marie 
1         2    Bob
2         1    Alex
3         1    Alec
3         2    Paul
3         3    Rex
```

Comment: "dataframe" is not terminology usually associated with SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An updatable CTE with a cumulative conditional `COUNT` seems to be what you are after:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (BlockID int,
                            Step int,
                            [Name] varchar(10));
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES(1,1,'Marie'),
      (1,2,'Bob'),
      (1,3,'John'),
      (1,4,'Lola'),
      (2,1,'Alex'),
      (2,2,'John'),
      (2,3,'Kate'),
      (2,4,'Herald'),
      (3,1,'Alec'),
      (3,2,'Paul'),
      (3,3,'Rex');
GO

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT COUNT(CASE [Name] WHEN 'John' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY BlockID ORDER BY Step) AS Johns
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE Johns >= 1;
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method uses an updatable CTE:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*,
             min(case when name = 'John' then step end) over (partition by block_id) as john_id
      from t
     )
delete from todelete
     where id >= john_id;
```

Or, if you prefer, a correlated subquery:

```
delete from t
    where id >= (select min(t2.id)
                 from t t2
                 where t2.blockid = t.blockid and t2.name = 'John'
                );
```

For performance, both of these can take advantage of an index on `(blockid, name, id)`.